# JAVA - non-static method add(E) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to insert `String` values (using a `Scanner`) into an `ArrayList`.

I am getting the error:

> non-static method add(E) cannot be referenced from a static context.

I assume the `add()` method is the problem - what other methods can I use to insert into an `ArrayList` that is static?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    private static List<String> strings;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            String s = scanner.nextLine();
            List.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `strings.add`

Comment: It should be `strings.add(s)`. Of course, you should initialize that variable first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add a string to `List` interface (`add()` method is not static) but should add it to your instance `List<String> strings`:

```
strings.add(s);
```

Also, you should initialize `strings`

```
private static List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

otherwise, you will get `NullPointerException`.